# How to delete mySQL JSON column element by id, instead of by index num

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sql-update

Provided a datasource:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usnistgov/oscal-content/master/examples/ssp/json/ssp-example.json

I have added this to a JSON column called `json_data` in a table called `ssp_models`, with a record uuid of `66c2a1c8-5830-48bd-8fdd-55a1c3a52888`.

[image: screenshot of how the record looks in myPHPAdmin]

I am able to GET records, INSERT records, and REMOVE records just fine from the "parties" node with that dataset.

However, it's the `JSON_REMOVE` part that's not working quite as I'd like.  Presently I can json_remove an entry via indexnum via:

```
UPDATE ssp_models 
   SET json_data = JSON_REMOVE(json_data, '$.\"system-security-plan\".metadata.parties[0]')
```

So that deletes entry [0] from 'parties' like you'd expect.

But what I *really* want is to be able to delete a record by uuid.  As you can see in the 'parties' section of data, uuid is an element in each entry:

```
parties: [

{

uuid: "3b2a5599-cc37-403f-ae36-5708fa804b27",

type: "organization",

name: "Enterprise Asset Owners"

},

{

uuid: "833ac398-5c9a-4e6b-acba-2a9c11399da0",

type: "organization",

name: "Enterprise Asset Administrators"

}....
```

So how can I somehow combine 'WHERE uuid = "3b2a5599-cc37-403f-ae36-5708fa804b27"' for removal into such a sql query when it's part of the JSON Document Store syntax?  (In that case, I'd expect it to remove the "Enterprise Asset Owners" entry along with it's type and uuid.  It's like we need to add a search-function as part of the deletion, but the examples I've been reading don't provide that as an option within json_remove:  https://database.guide/json_remove-remove-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

`JSON_SEARCH()` function might be used to find the element's index with the `uuid` value to be deleted such as

```
UPDATE ssp_models 
   SET json_data = JSON_REMOVE(json_data, 
                       REPLACE(
                        JSON_UNQUOTE(
                            JSON_SEARCH(json_data, 
                                        'one', 
                                        '3b2a5599-cc37-403f-ae36-5708fa804b27')
                            ),'.uuid',
                       ''))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=62b53c8a3d1d2d7e1da2a9a636f9391f)</kbd>